# Selecting the latest records by timestampz and groupid

Tags: database, postgresql, timestamp, greatest-n-per-group

I'm trying to return the latest records for a store based on the TIMESTAMPZ that was used when imported. I'm on Postgres 9.5 and this is my query I got from stackoverflowing on some threads here:

```
select p.*
from store_products p
inner join(
   select storeid, sku, max(lastupdated) AS lastupdated
   from store_products
   group by storeid, sku
)sp on p.storeid= sp.storeidand p.lastupdated = sp.lastupdated
```

This gives me the latest *products* by each store (and SKU), which is great (we have about 30 stores), but I'm noticing that the query takes (for 6M records) around 4minutes to gather the data.

So if we had this as my data:

```
PID | StoreID | SKU | lastupdated
1   | 1       | 1a1 | 2017-02-02 18:22:30
2   | 1       | 1b1 | 2017-02-02 18:21:30
3   | 1       | 1a1 | 2017-01-16 11:22:30
4   | 2       | 1a1 | 2017-02-02 18:21:30
5   | 2       | 1a1 | 2017-02-01 18:21:00
6   | 3       | 1a1 | 2017-02-02 18:21:30
7   | 3       | 1g1 | 2017-02-01 18:21:30
```

I'm getting this:

```
PID | StoreID | SKU | lastupdated
1   | 1       | 1a1 | 2017-02-02 18:22:30
2   | 1       | 1b1 | 2017-02-02 18:21:30
4   | 2       | 1a1 | 2017-02-02 18:21:30
6   | 3       | 1a1 | 2017-02-02 18:21:30
```

Is there a better way of us being able to import these store snapshots so the query above is easier to digest for Postgres - faster? Are there any indexes we should add? here's the explain:

```
Hash Join  (cost=2358424.92..2715814.08 rows=311 width=371)
  Hash Cond: ((lp.storeid = p.storeid) AND (lp.lastupdated = p.lastupdated))
  ->  Subquery Scan on lp  (cost=1676046.30..1737513.85 rows=62125 width=12)
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1676046.30..1736892.60 rows=62125 width=108)
              Group Key: store_products.storeid, store_products.sku
              ->  Sort  (cost=1676046.30..1691102.56 rows=6022505 width=108)
                    Sort Key: store_products.storeid, store_products.sku
                    ->  Seq Scan on store_products  (cost=0.00..297973.05 rows=6022505 width=108)
  ->  Hash  (cost=297973.05..297973.05 rows=6022505 width=371)
        ->  Seq Scan on store_products p  (cost=0.00..297973.05 rows=6022505 width=371)
```

Our Postgres DBA is on holidays and most of us aren't really cluey about what to do here.

**Backstory...**

We get a daily dump of store products from multiple stores in JSON. Each store is determined by storeid, they're imported as one chunky JSON file with all the stores and their products. Each entry has it's own lastupdated | TIMESTAMPZ field. This is backed by a trigger to auto update that field if someone decides to update it later (for auditing purposes). Daily, there's around 2-3K worth of store_products being inserted into this table, we're currently not de-duping this data (so a price may have changed, it may not have, we don't seem to care yet, we just INSERT). I think we'll dedupe soon.

Let me give you a basic schema:

```
CREATE TABLE store_products
(
    id BIGINT DEFAULT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    storeid INTEGER,
    ...etc etc...
    lastupdated TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()
);
```

There's an FK for storeid to the store table etc.

Comment: "*This gives me the latest product by each store, ... but I really need all the latest products by each store*" - I don't understand that sentence. There can only be one "latest" product for each store. Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) Did you check the many answers for [tag:greatest-n-per-group]

Comment: Will do, thanks @a_horse_with_no_name I will, yes that sentence is a bit awry... I will fix it with some samples and after looking through the greatest-n-per-group I came up with the above query. I think my situation is a bit different because of the unfortunate separation by tiemstamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) will make it simpler:

```
select distinct on (storeid, sku) *
from store_products
order by storeid, sku, lastupdated desc
```

Notice that the order by clause is mandatory to determine which row will be returned.

Create an index on (storeid, sku, lastupdated) or just (storeid, sku) if not enough timestamps to be worth the extra sized index.

Comment: Thank-you, much cleaner syntax and the indexing really helped too.

Answer (score 0):

try using ROW number -over partition by clause and use of temp table like below

```
select *
from (
    select p.*
    from store_products p
    inner join (
        select
            storeid,
            max(lastupdated) AS lastupdated,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY storedid ORDER BY lastupdated DESC) AS RowNo
        from store_products
        group by storeid
    ) sp on p.storeid= sp.storeidand p.lastupdated = sp.lastupdated
) temp
where
order by temp.RowNo
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! I updated my question to reflect the SKU i missed in my first post.